# Accessibility VoiceOver - UITableView keeps jumping to top of table as user scrolls down the list

Tags: uitableview, accessibility, voiceover

I have implemented a UITableView and filled it with a long list of data with sections. With VoiceOver enabled, as the user tries to scroll down the screen to see the cells past the bottom of the screen, the table keeps jumping back to the top and starts reading over again.

I cannot find any reason why it would do this, the table acts as it should with VoiceOver disabled.

Thanks,
Lynn

Comment: Lynn, is the table the last thing on the page or is their more? VoiceOver is for people with vision imparments, so you don't need to visually see something in VO. I don't have much experience with VO, but my guess is that it doesn't allow you to jump around the table quickly. So it sees you taping in the last cell so it jumps to row 1 col 1 of the table.

Comment: Ryan, you are right, with VO on, it doesn't allow you to jump through the table quickly. It is also more sluggish on older devices. So, that makes sense what you are saying. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Screen readers allow you to jump around in a table. VO on devices are linear for the most part.

Comment: @LynnS a VoiceOver user can scroll with three fingers to quickly scroll one "page" at a time. This is true for all scroll views and thus also for table views.

Comment: @RyanB You don't have to be blind to use VoiceOver and the VoiceOver users I've spoken with don't use it very linearly at all. They remember in which corner of the screen certain button are. They use gestures to scroll. Some of them even use both their hands when typing on the keyboard etc.

Comment: **Relevant to the question:** That doesn't sound like the behavior I'm expecting either. Are you doing anything while the user is scrolling? perhaps reloading the table view to load more data?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist That's true, but what I mean, on a computer, I can say jump to that table, and go to row 3 col 2. On a phone, I believe you can say jump to the table, but once in you can't say jump to row 3 col 2.